# El grabador de audio no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me interesa un grabador de audio, buscando en internet encontré este grabador pero no funciona... se activa el microfono pero no graba y el botón de parar y escuchar tampoco, cómo puedo hacer para que funcione en cualquier navegador y de manera local en mi pc?

¿O necesito un servidor? el codigo lo probé en w3schools

En casi todas las páginas de internet solo aparece este ejemplo.
me interesa saber que problemas tiene este codigo o si hay otra manera más simple de hacerlo ya que entiendo muy poco de javascript.

```js
   //Función en caso de error
   var error = function(e) {
    console.log('¡No pude grabarte!', e);
   };
   //Función cuando todo tenga exito
   var exito = function(s) {
    var context = new webkitAudioContext(); //Conectamos con nuestra entrada de audio
    var flujo = context.createMediaStreamSource(s); //Obtenemos el flujo de datos desde la fuente
    recorder = new Recorder(flujo); //Todo el flujo de datos lo pasamos a nuestra libreria para procesarlo en esta instancia
    recorder.record(); //Ejecutamos la función para procesarlo
   }
   //Convertirmos el objeto en URL
   window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
   navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
   var recorder; //Es nuestra variable para usar la libreria Recorder.js
   var audio = document.querySelector('audio'); //Seleccionamos la etiqueta audio para enviarte el audio y escucharla
   //Funcion para iniciar el grabado
   function grabar() {
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) { //Preguntamos si nuestro navegador es compatible con esta función que permite usar microfono o camara web
     navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, exito, error); //En caso de que si, habilitamos audio y se ejecutan las funciones, en caso de exito o error.
     document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = "Estamos grabando...";
    } else {
     console.log('¡Tu navegador no es compatible!, ¿No lo vas a acutalizar?'); //Si no es compatible, enviamos este mensaje.
    }
   }
   //Funcion para parar la grabación y escucharla
   function parar() {
    recorder.stop(); //Paramos la grabación
    recorder.exportWAV(function(s) { //Exportamos en formato WAV el audio 
     audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(s); //Y convertimos el valor devuelto en URL para pasarlo a nuestro reproductor.
    });
    document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = "Paramos la grabación y ahora escuchala...";
   }
  </script>

<script>
(function(window){

  var WORKER_PATH = 'recorderWorker.js';

  var Recorder = function(source, cfg){
    var config = cfg || {};
    var bufferLen = config.bufferLen || 4096;
    this.context = source.context;
    this.node = this.context.createJavaScriptNode(bufferLen, 2, 2);
    var worker = new Worker(config.workerPath || WORKER_PATH);
    worker.postMessage({
      command: 'init',
      config: {
        sampleRate: this.context.sampleRate
      }
    });
    var recording = false,
      currCallback;

    this.node.onaudioprocess = function(e){
      if (!recording) return;
      worker.postMessage({
        command: 'record',
        buffer: [
          e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0),
          e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1)
        ]
      });
    }

    this.configure = function(cfg){
      for (var prop in cfg){
        if (cfg.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
          config[prop] = cfg[prop];
        }
      }
    }

    this.record = function(){
      recording = true;
    }

    this.stop = function(){
      recording = false;
    }

    this.clear = function(){
      worker.postMessage({ command: 'clear' });
    }

    this.getBuffer = function(cb) {
      currCallback = cb || config.callback;
      worker.postMessage({ command: 'getBuffer' })
    }

    this.exportWAV = function(cb, type){
      currCallback = cb || config.callback;
      type = type || config.type || 'audio/wav';
      if (!currCallback) throw new Error('Callback not set');
      worker.postMessage({
        command: 'exportWAV',
        type: type
      });
    }

    worker.onmessage = function(e){
      var blob = e.data;
      currCallback(blob);
    }

    source.connect(this.node);
    this.node.connect(this.context.destination);    //this should not be necessary
  };

  Recorder.forceDownload = function(blob, filename){
    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
    var link = window.document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename || 'output.wav';
    var click = document.createEvent("Event");
    click.initEvent("click", true, true);
    link.dispatchEvent(click);
  }

  window.Recorder = Recorder;

})(window);
var recLength = 0,
  recBuffersL = [],
  recBuffersR = [],
  sampleRate;

this.onmessage = function(e){
  switch(e.data.command){
    case 'init':
      init(e.data.config);
      break;
    case 'record':
      record(e.data.buffer);
      break;
    case 'exportWAV':
      exportWAV(e.data.type);
      break;
    case 'getBuffer':
      getBuffer();
      break;
    case 'clear':
      clear();
      break;
  }
};

function init(config){
  sampleRate = config.sampleRate;
}

function record(inputBuffer){
  recBuffersL.push(inputBuffer[0]);
  recBuffersR.push(inputBuffer[1]);
  recLength += inputBuffer[0].length;
}

function exportWAV(type){
  var bufferL = mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength);
  var bufferR = mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength);
  var interleaved = interleave(bufferL, bufferR);
  var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
  var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: type });

  this.postMessage(audioBlob);
}

function getBuffer() {
  var buffers = [];
  buffers.push( mergeBuffers(recBuffersL, recLength) );
  buffers.push( mergeBuffers(recBuffersR, recLength) );
  this.postMessage(buffers);
}

function clear(){
  recLength = 0;
  recBuffersL = [];
  recBuffersR = [];
}

function mergeBuffers(recBuffers, recLength){
  var result = new Float32Array(recLength);
  var offset = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < recBuffers.length; i++){
    result.set(recBuffers[i], offset);
    offset += recBuffers[i].length;
  }
  return result;
}

function interleave(inputL, inputR){
  var length = inputL.length + inputR.length;
  var result = new Float32Array(length);

  var index = 0,
    inputIndex = 0;

  while (index < length){
    result[index++] = inputL[inputIndex];
    result[index++] = inputR[inputIndex];
    inputIndex++;
  }
  return result;
}

function floatTo16BitPCM(output, offset, input){
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset+=2){
    var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
    output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7FFF, true);
  }
}

function writeString(view, offset, string){
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
  }
}

function encodeWAV(samples){
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + samples.length * 2);
  var view = new DataView(buffer);

  /* RIFF identifier */
  writeString(view, 0, 'RIFF');
  /* file length */
  view.setUint32(4, 32 + samples.length * 2, true);
  /* RIFF type */
  writeString(view, 8, 'WAVE');
  /* format chunk identifier */
  writeString(view, 12, 'fmt ');
  /* format chunk length */
  view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
  /* sample format (raw) */
  view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
  /* channel count */
  view.setUint16(22, 2, true);
  /* sample rate */
  view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
  /* byte rate (sample rate * block align) */
  view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
  /* block align (channel count * bytes per sample) */
  view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
  /* bits per sample */
  view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
  /* data chunk identifier */
  writeString(view, 36, 'data');
  /* data chunk length */
  view.setUint32(40, samples.length * 2, true);

  floatTo16BitPCM(view, 44, samples);

  return view;
}
```

```css
  audio{
   margin:20px;
  }
  p{
   margin:10px;
  }
  input[type="button"]{
   background:#CCC;
   border:none;
   border-radius:5px;
   cursor:pointer;
   font-size:1em;
   padding:5px;
  }
  input[type="button"]:hover{
   background:#666;
  }
```

```html
 <audio controls autoplay></audio>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="recorder.js"> </script>
  <p></p>
  <input onclick="grabar()" type="button" value="Grabar ahora" />
  <input onclick="parar()" type="button" value="Parar y escuchar" />
```

Comment: Mas allá de la recompensa que des sobre esta pregunta... es demasiado amplia... y esta sujeta a puntuaciones negativas... y así esta sucediendo te sugiero que lo edites.

Comment: Fijate que el archivo 'recorderWorker.js' ( el source del worker que graba ) esté en la misma carpeta que el html/js. No hace falta servidor para capturar audio o video, localmente funciona si abris directo el html en el navegador. Si lo pones en un servidor tiene que ser https. Opcionalmente podes basarte en [recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) que usa la librería [inline-worker](https://github.com/mohayonao/inline-worker), o evitar totalmente los workers y armarlo con el API [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).

Comment: un ejemplo con mediarecorder lo tenes en https://codepen.io/miguelao/pen/wzVMJb?editors=0010 en tu caso para grabar sólo audio tenes que poner en las constraints `"video":false, "audio" :true` y el mimeType a `audio/webm` o `audio/ogg` ( se repite al crear el blob para descarga )

Comment: Me da errores: getUserMedia() failed: TypeError: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads of URL.createObjectURL.

Comment: @Header90, ¿solo necesitas grabar y reproducir lo grabado?

Comment: Sí es lo que quiero hacer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mi solución se basa en utilizar la [`Media​Stream Recording API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API).

En base a esta condición voy a tratar de responder a todas las preguntas por separado y en un orden que permita realizar una respuesta entendible.

---

> [...]cómo puedo hacer para que funcione en cualquier navegador[...]

Esto no es posible, ya que esta API [no esta disponible en todos los navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API#Browser_compatibility).

> [...] necesito un servidor [...]

No, ya que es una herramienta provista por el navegador y no le importa si la página esta online o en la PC.

> [...] hay otra manera más simple de hacerlo [...]

La solución que planteo debajo, desde mi punto de vista es simple (*dudo que sea la más simple*).

**Atención:** El snippet no funciona por las políticas de sandbox establecidas para el mismo. [Acá dejo un enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/14khadsj/) donde se lo puede ver en funcionamiento.

```html
<audio id="audio" controls></audio>
<p></p>
<input id="record" type="button" value="Grabar" />
<input id="pause" type="button" value="Pausar" disabled />
<input id="resume" type="button" value="Continuar" disabled />
<input id="stop" type="button" value="Parar" disabled />
<script>

if (navigator.mediaDevices) {

  var chunks = [];
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  var record = document.getElementById('record');
  var pause = document.getElementById('pause');
  var resume = document.getElementById('resume');
  var stop = document.getElementById('stop');


  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  })
    .then(function(stream) {

    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    record.onclick = function() {
     if (mediaRecorder.state != 'inactive') {
       return;
      }
     record.disabled = true;
      pause.disabled = false;
      stop.disabled = false;
      mediaRecorder.start();
    }
    pause.onclick = function() {
     if (mediaRecorder.state != 'recording') {
       return;
      }
     pause.disabled = true;
      resume.disabled = false;
      mediaRecorder.pause();
    }
    resume.onclick = function() {
     if (mediaRecorder.state != 'paused') {
       return;
      }
     pause.disabled = false;
      resume.disabled = true;
      mediaRecorder.resume();
    }
    stop.onclick = function() {
     if (mediaRecorder.state == 'inactive') {
       return;
      }
     record.disabled = false;
      pause.disabled = true;
      resume.disabled = true;
      stop.disabled = true;
      mediaRecorder.stop();
    }

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
      audio.controls = true;
      var blob = new Blob(chunks, {
        'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'
      });
      
      chunks = [];
      audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    }
  })
    .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('The following error occurred: ' + err);
  })
}
</script>
```

> [...] y de manera local en mi pc? [...]

Pasos:

1. Crear un archivo HTML, por ejemplo `grabador.html`
2. Copiar el contenido del snippet dentro y guardar
3. Hacer doble clik sobre el archivo y abrirlo con un navegador
4. Permitir el uso de micrófono y listo!